# How to use Webpack Module Federation plugin with create-react-app without ejecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-module-federation

Is there a way to use module federation using create-react-app without ejecting?
I want to convert my existing react applications(created using CRA) to micro-frontends.

Answer (score 12):

> Answering because this question is top for Google searches `CRA with Module Federation`

##### Update 25 Jan 2022 - CRA 5 has been released previous answers are not relevant in 2022 as CRA 5 supports Webpack 5.

##### My [GitHub template](https://github.com/DalSoft/create-react-app-webpack-5-module-federation-tailwind-typeScript) has been updated to CRA 5 just use that for a CRA Module Federation example.

##### I've left my answer for historical value

<s>Update 17 Nov 2021 - based on this answer I've created a [GitHub template](https://github.com/DalSoft/create-react-app-webpack-5-module-federation-tailwind-2-typeScript) to make it easier for anyone else trying to do module federation with CRA.</s>

## Try the craco-module-federation plugin for CRACO

Take a look at the [craco-module-federation](https://github.com/hasanayan/craco-module-federation) repo for an example of CRA working with Module Federation.

To support Module Federation you need the [craco-module-federation](https://github.com/hasanayan/craco-module-federation) CRACO plugin (or to write your own CRACO config) to overwrite CRA webpack config.

#### You also need to be running the alpha version of `react-scripts`, and update any dependencies.

[craco-module-federation](https://github.com/hasanayan/craco-module-federation) is a plugin for [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) that does the heavy lifting required.

The steps for getting CRA and Module Federation working are:

##### Use Create React App 5 with webpack 5 support

`npx create-react-app@next --scripts-version=@next --template=cra-template@next my-js-app`

More info here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/discussions/11278

For an existing app delete node_modules, and install the alpha version of  `react-scripts`. Then resolve any dependencies issues.

##### Install CRACO

`npm install @craco/craco --save`

Change your package.json scripts to run craco:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "craco start",
  "build": "craco build"
}
```

##### Use CRACO config to overwrite webpack config

Either install the craco-module-federation plugin, or write your own CRACO config to overwrite webpack's config to add the ModuleFederationPlugin.

##### Add your Module Federation config

Either to `modulefederation.config.js` if your using the craco-module-federation plugin, or to `craco.config.js` if you configuring without the craco-module-federation plugin.

### Be aware

- **Create React App 5 with webpack 5 support is in Alpha, you may run into issues.**
- **craco-module-federation IS NOT PRODUCTION READY**

Comment: I'm following your updated example. I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')` on the host application side. Remote seems to be creating the RemoteEntry.js file correctly.

Comment: Template is working perfectly for many people. Raise a GitHub issue with steps to reproduce and I'll try and help you.

Answer (score 2):

react-scripts still uses webpack 4.x.x. You can track the migration [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9994).

What you can do in the meantime is use [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco), an amazing tool to set custom configurations on top of CRA's without ejecting.

Follow the instructions on how to set CRACO in your project, is fair simple.
Then install webpack 5, after attempting `yarn start` or `build` you'll get a warning from react-script saying webpack 5 shouldn't be installed. A workaround, as they state, add `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to a *.env* file.
This is a temporary fix while CRA's team upgrades, I strongly suggest you remove it later on. Keep using CRACO is totally fine though.
Here's a sample of a basic *.craco.js* file:

```
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const allDeps = require("../package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: ModuleFederationPlugin,
      options: {
        shared: {
          ...allDeps,
          'styled-components': {
            singleton: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
});
```

And remember to change your package.json scripts to run craco:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "craco start",
  "build": "craco build"
}
```

You can even create a custom plugin, put it on top of CRA, and reuse it.

Comment: Hi , is the example you show up above working for you? I have some error with you code.. tanks

Answer (score 0):

No. In order to bump the version of the current webpack for CRA you need to eject. Moreover, CRA at the moment would be on webpack v4, which is no good for module federation. So you need to wait until authors of CRA will move on with webpack v5 or create your own template and implement federation into it ))
If you want to be on track, follow https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9994

Answer (score 0):

you can use a plugin called [`craco-plugin-micro-frontend`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-plugin-micro-frontend)

```sh
npm install --save-dev craco-plugin-micro-frontend
```

and use it your `craco.config.js`

```js
const microFrontedPlugin = require('craco-plugin-micro-frontend');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: microFrontedPlugin,
      options: {
        orgName: 'my-org',
        fileName: 'my-app.js', // should same as package main
        entry: 'src/index.injectable.js', //defaults to src/index.injectable.js,
        orgPackagesAsExternal: false, // defaults to false. marks packages that has @my-org prefix as external so they are not included in the bundle
        reactPackagesAsExternal: true, // defaults to true. marks react and react-dom as external so they are not included in the bundle
        externals: ['react-router', 'react-router-dom'], // defaults to []. marks the specified modules as external so they are not included in the bundle
        minimize: false, // defaults to false, sets optimization.minimize value
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2', // defaults to umd
        outputPath: 'dist',
        customJestConfig: {}, // custom jest configurations
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

your `package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "build:lib": "REACT_APP_INJECTABLE=true craco build",
    ...
   }
```

for more info can read here:  https://github.com/m-nathani/craco-plugin-micro-frontend#readme